# How to use shared array between function calls in objective C

Tags: iphone

I have one array.
I want that array to retain its value between function calls of from single class function.

I have function that is called every time  page is loaded.

This function displays all the data stored in array right from application launches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your array in appDelegate class. Or I think it will be better to make some class to store shared data and make an instance of this class in your appDelegate.